# Direct links to Google translate blocked

Tags: links, translation, captcha, google-translate

I have a blog where i post articles gathered from the net (french) and sometimes when i want to add a foreign language but interesting article, i just put the href value as :

```
https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=en&tl=fr&u=https//www.article.com/some.html
```

so the user can click the title (in french) and be redirected to the google translated page directly, but the problem is sometimes (several times) Google reject the link returning the error :

```
We're sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries.
```

With no Recaptcha to allow the translation. Is there any solution to avoid this reject or is there any paid tool to translate links based on queries rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a translate API https://cloud.google.com/translate which has a free component and then becomes a paid service.

```
First 500,000 characters per month = Free (applied as $10 credit every month)
500,000 to 1 billion characters per month = $20 per million characters
Over 1 billion characters per month = Contact a sales representative to discuss discount pricing.
```

This is different to linking via a URL, but as you have already discovered, if you don't use the API you quickly trigger a block.

Comment: So approximately 1 webpage count an average of 150000 CHAR, that lead me to 20$ for 6 page ? let's say i have 10000 visitors per month and half of them click on the translated link = 150000 * 5000 = 750 000 000 char = 15000 $ .?

Comment: I mean is the rate applied for each user that click on the link or for the article translated once ?

Comment: @Stalkium These are questions you need to ask Google, not here.

Comment: i will, thanks for the advise, answer accepted